# QDomNode Class read value of child in qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom

I want to change "A" in Apple, in key which value is 1 to "D", in this code 2 items should be replaced. I tried something like this, but nothing happens.

```
 <C>
    <B>  
    <Key value="1">
       <Apple>A</Apple>
    </Key>
    <Key value="2">
       <Apple>A</Apple>
    </Key>
    <Key value="3">
       <Apple>A</Apple>
    </Key>
    <Key value="1">
       <Apple>A</Apple>
    </Key>
    </B>
 </C>
```

Qt:

```
QDomNodeList roots = doc.elementsByTagName("Key");

for (int i = 0; i < roots.size(); ++i) {
    QDomElement domElement = roots.at(i).toElement();
    QDomAttr attribute = domElement.attributeNode("value");
    if (attribute.value() == "1") { 
        domElement.firstChild().setNodeValue("D");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the `domElement.firstChild()` refers to the `<Apple>` element node, **not** to its content. The value inside the `<Apple>` is **also** a node ([text node](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomnode.html#NodeType-enum)), that is why it is located one level deeper in the DOM hierarchy:

- `domElement` — **`<Key>`**
- `domElement.firstChild()` — **`<Apple>`**
- `domElement.firstChild().firstChild()` — **`A`**

So you will also have to get the first child of the `<Apple>` element node:

```
domElement.firstChild().firstChild().setNodeValue("D");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
if (attribute.value() == "1")
```

Comment: no, in program I have QString, I just made a mistake in example.